# ASP.Net Core 7 Error redirecting to Blazor page under Areas section

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, blazor-server-side

[image]

[image]

`_Host.cshtml.cs`:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login/Index", new { area = "Identity" });
```

Error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

/Account/Login/Index
/Account/Login
/_Host
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
```

Comment: How about `return RedirectToPage("/Identity/Account/Login/Index");` ? Does it works or not ?

Comment: I don't think it is due to `return RedirectToPage("/Identity/Account/Login/Index");`. I remove `_Host.cshtml.cs` and `curl`ing the root of the web applicatio also results in the same error.

Comment: Could you share the sample project without any sensitive information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because I use ASP.Net Core Identity scaffolded pages which has the Login in `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/<foo>.cshtml`. I tried to move them into `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login/<foo>.cshtml` and ASP.Net Core is confused by that! Duh!